# Is old un-used potting soil still good for use

Tags: fruits, potting-soil

I've had a larger bag of potting soil sitting outside on a deck for about two years.
Recently I decided to try and grow fruits and I was wondering if the potting soil would still be okay to use

Comment: From experience, no problem

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should be alright. It might, however, no longer be sterile if the bag was open or had any holes.